# Как настроить phpmyadmin на centOS 7

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, centos, iptables, httpd

Здравствуйте! Не получается настроить `apache` и `phpmyadmin` на VPS с `CentOS 7`.

Устанавливал как обычно `yum instal httpd phpmyadmin`
Но при установке `phpmyadmin` даже не было окна установщика с настройками, под какой сервер, пароль и т.д, просто установился.

**iptables:**

```
*filter

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# SSH #
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# dns server ports #
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# game server #
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT

# FTP #
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 21 -j ACCEPT

# MYSQL #
-A INPUT -s 37.59.233.93 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 185.61.137.99 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
"iptables" 62L, 1749C
```

Все равно не работает, уже не знаю что и делать.

Comment: правила не работают ?

Comment: "Все равно не работает" - что не работает? Вы же врачу не говорите "Доктор, у меня болит!"? Опишите конкретно - в чём проблема заключается? На каком этапе выполнения какого действия какая ошибка происходит? А вообще конфигурационный файл PMA - config.inc.php. Там он и настраивается. Если файла нет - то создайте его на основе файла config.sample.inc.php.

Comment: На этапе когда все успешно установлено, все нужные порты открыты, службы запущены и ничего не работает. А именно при переходе на IP или домен машины просто ошибка, сайт недоступен.

Comment: @francoder какая ошибка? 404 ?

Comment: В общем это из-за iptables, отключив его всё заработало, iptables ставили хостеры, я просто не знаю, помогает ли он нам при ддос атаке, или все-таки у хостера еще какие-то методы стоят для отражения, поэтому и не трогали iptables

Comment: @francoder отключите второе правило или разрешите 443 порт и все заработает